# Creating A View Code in SQL

Tags: sql

So my question may seem easy but I'm a beginner.

[image]

What is wrong with this Code and how can I edit it to add students not taking any course?

Comment: Take a look at the red squiggle. There's one under AS. Can you see the issue?

Comment: Additionally the inner joins would need to become left outer so all students are returned.  Not just those with enrollment our courses having professors.  change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`  in all 3 cases to return all students regardless of enrollment and course record existence.

Comment: Even a beginner would be given an error message, one that would probably have been helpful to answering this for your self.

Comment: Thank you all a lot for the explanation. I still didn't get the red squiggle. I don't understand the issue itself.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the comma after p.lastname on line 3.

Answer (score 1):

> *I don't understand the issue itself.*

It helps if you break-up each entry of the select list to individual lines, I like to do this so the comma is at the beginning of the line, like so:

```
SELECT 
       s.id AS StudentID  -- this column alias "StudentID" works
     , s.lastName         -- no alias needed here

     , p.lastName         -- but need alias here, where is the alias?
     , AS Professor       -- Ooops, comma in the wrong place

FROM ...
```

I assume you understand "column alias"
if not try [SQL - Alias Syntax](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-alias-syntax.htm)